# "this" in fat arrow function vs compiled output through babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Can someone explain this behavior? 
This code snippet outputs `Window`

```
(()=>{
  console.log(this);
})()
```

but its compiled output using babel is

```
"use strict";

(function () {
  console.log(undefined);
})();
```

this outputs `undefined`

If babel is just compiling, shouldn't the output be same in both the cases? Why `this` translates to `undefined` in babel output?

Comment: Generally the expectation is that you'd be using `this` within a function that's scoped to some object, so that wouldn't be an issue. My guess is that Babel is using a heuristic approach for performance reasons but that's just a guess. Alternatively it could be considered a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Babel assumes your input code is a *module*, and modules are interpreted in *strict mode*. Therefore the above code when pasted into the browser's developer console is rather equvivalent to:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  (()=>{
    console.log(this);
  })();
})();
```

Which prints `undefined`.